# Why does sleep in a thread have no puts output?

Tags: ruby

I'm using Ruby 2.0, Cygwin, and Windows 8. The following program produces no output; it will loop forever and not `puts` the time.

```
hi = Thread.new do
  while true do
    puts Time.now # or call tick function
    sleep 1
  end
end
hi.join
```

Am I missing something?

I want the functionality to be:

- Do something
- Wait for 3-10 seconds
- Do it again etc.

Comment: You can also use 'p' instead of 'puts' to return output from inside a Thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your output is buffered ([`$stdout.sync`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-sync) defaults to `false`). To flush all output immediately, start your script with:

```
$stdout.sync = true
```